# How to restore deleted tex in UITextView?

Tags: xcode, uitextview

In a `UITextView`, when I input something, for example, "foobar", then I delete "bar", and when I click a Redo button, the text would restore to "foobar".
I tried using `NSUndoManager`, but it undid all text typed in. So, how can I implement this function?

Comment: store text changed into mutablearray. hold a undocounter and set the text based on undocounter as array index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSUndoManager is able to implement this function.
1.notice before use -undo registerUndo method.
2.record text should change the text.
3.call -undo and change the target textview.text.